# How to show widgets in new window witch is widget without using layouts

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, window

I don't find anything how to show widgets like qlabel qpushbutton and qtextedit in new widget window.Here is my code:

This is the class where I create new widget window witch show but without the widgets.

```
class PasswordForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Password")
        self.setFixedWidth(400)
        self.setFixedHeight(300)
        self.label = QLabel("Enter Admin Password:")
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 211, 31))
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.admin_pass_input = QLineEdit()
        self.admin_pass_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 161, 25))
        self.admin_pass_input.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.admin_pass_input.setObjectName("admin_pass_input")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("OK")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 80, 89, 25))
```

This is the function where I call the new window to show:

```
 def clicked(self, action):
    self.p_form = PasswordForm()
    self.p_form.show()
```

MineWindows is generated by PyQT5 Designer.

Comment: What is the reason for not using layouts in that window?

Comment: Just I can't find what layout to use to positioning like I want

Comment: there are very few situations and specific requirements that can justify avoiding layout management, and not being able to "find what layout" is not amongst them. For instance, if I use a highDPI screen, or a big sized font by default due to visual impairment, any widget in your UI would have their text partially hidden; layouts ensure that none of this happens. You can reproduce your same concept of UI using layouts, you only need knowledge about their usage and experience with them. Also remember that layouts can be nested, so you can have a grid layout inside a vertical one, for instance.

Comment: I suggest you to take some time to get experienced with layouts using Designer, so that you can get better and faster understanding, then try to recreate those layouts by code and see the differences. You can even *study* (**not** edit!) the code generated by the pyuic utility, in order to see how Qt creates those layouts.

Comment: Thank you I will try them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic rule of Qt: A QWidget (QLineEdit, QPushButton, etc) will be part of another QWidget if it is a child of this or a child of a QWidget that is part of the QWidget.

So the task of a layout is not only to manage the geometry of the QWidgets but also to establish as the parent of the QWidgets that manages the QWidget where it is placed.

In your case you just have to pass the parent:

```
self.label = QLabel("Enter Admin Password:", self)
```

```
self.admin_pass_input = QLineEdit(self)
```

```
self.pushButton = QPushButton("OK", self)
```